# Dynamically Loaded ImageView not centered

Tags: android, android-layout

I am loading some information dynamically after the user chooses an item from a Dose Type spinner. The information is inside a relative layout located at the bottom of the main screen.

The relative layout has an imageview that is dynamically loaded based on the selected item in the spinner.The image is resized using picasso. **It seems the resizing using picasso is causing the issue but can't do without...coz the original image is too big.**

The imageview is not centered...no matter what, it always displays at the top left of the relative layout.

The imageview in question is the 2nd one in the layout...the one with id @+id/imgDoseTypeInfo

Please help

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rb4kw.jpg)

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_help"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDoseTypeName_AddDrugActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="sample text"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
            android:textColor="@color/normaltextcolor"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblDoseTypeDesc_AddDrugActivity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/lblDoseTypeName_AddDrugActivity"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
            android:text="@string/pediatric_calc_info"
            android:textColor="@color/normaltextcolor"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgDoseTypeInfo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>


cmbDosageType.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            selectedDoseType = (DosageType) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            lyDoseTypInfo.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            LoadDoseTypeInfo(selectedDoseType.getCalcType(), selectedDoseType.name);


        }
    });

    private void LoadDoseTypeInfo(String calcType, String doseName) {

    String doseDesc = "";

    switch (calcType) {

        case "vol_liquid":

            doseDesc = getResources().getString(R.string.vol_liquid_info);
            break;
        case "num_tablets":

            doseDesc = getResources().getString(R.string.num_tablets_info);
            break;
        case "pediatric_calc":

            doseDesc = getResources().getString(R.string.pediatric_calc_info);
            break;
        case "dose_bodyweight_tablet":

            doseDesc = getResources().getString(R.string.dose_bodyweight_info);
            break;
        case "dose_bodyweight_liquid":

            doseDesc = getResources().getString(R.string.dose_bodyweight_info);
            break;
        case "dose_bodyweight_unit":

            doseDesc = getResources().getString(R.string.dose_bodyweight_info);
            break;

    }

    lblDoseTypeName.setText(doseName);
    lblDoseTypeDesc.setText(doseDesc);

    Picasso.with(getApplicationContext())
            .load(R.drawable.vol_liquid)
            .resize(600,600)
            .into(imgDoseTypeInfo);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Use `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` as `ImageView`'s attribute.
- Remove the `android:layout_below="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"` in your code .

Try this .

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_help"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDoseTypeName_AddDrugActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sample text"
        android:textColor="@color/normaltextcolor"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblDoseTypeDesc_AddDrugActivity"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lblDoseTypeName_AddDrugActivity"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="@string/pediatric_calc_info"
        android:textColor="@color/normaltextcolor"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDoseTypeInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry android:layout_centerInParent="true" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `<RelativeLayout>` please use below code to make image in center of parent layout

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgDoseTypeInfo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Comment: Please use this code in your java file ...       ImageView  image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgDoseTypeInfo);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) image.getLayoutParams();
lp.addRule(0);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT );
image.setLayoutParams(lp);

Comment: @JohnDoe Can you please upvote the answer mentioned in comment?

Answer (score 0):

I think your relative Layout width is not match parent need more clarification before that try this and below code android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblDoseTypeName_AddDrugActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="sample text"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:textColor="#313131"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblDoseTypeDesc_AddDrugActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
    android:layout_below="@+id/lblDoseTypeName_AddDrugActivity"
    android:text="pediatric_calc_info"
    android:textColor="#313131"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgDoseTypeInfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imgHelpIcon_AddDrugActivity"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```